# STL - Adding values to a vector stored within an STL map

Tags: c++, c++11

I have an STL map:

```
std::map<std::string, std::vector<int> > my_map;
```

I have two variables:

```
string name;
int age;
```

The value of these variables changes but essentially what I am looking to do is:

1. If, key name does not exist create key name and add age to vector.
2. Else, key name does exist add age to vector.

Eventually I will have a map containing peoples name and the ages of people with those names stored in an integer vector.

I can't for the life of me work out the syntax to do this. Please help :(.

Andrew

Comment: Add age to what vector? And "create key name" with what value?

Comment: Where did you get that map from? Try `std::map<std::string,int>` if you want to map a name of type `std::string` to an age of type `int`.

Comment: First post. Had a formatting error. Have a look now that Daniel has corrected. :)

Comment: Do you want a map like map<string, vector<int> > (basically map that stores ages of all people named "Andrew" in one vector and of all people named "Nick" in another) or something completely different?

Comment: Sorry I posted the wrong code.... Long day....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After your update, it's simply

```
my_map[ "Daniel" ].push_back( 40 );
my_map[ name ].push_back( age );
```

works for both cases, whether the key existed or not.

Comment: TY for reply. I need to work out statistics on the ages at a later point e.g average age. So need all ages stored.

Answer (score 1):

Given the map below:

```
 std::map<std::string,int> mymap;

 // Whether the key exists or not it will put something on the key.
 // So, if it does not exist it will create it, and if it exists it will
 // just replace it.
 mymap["somestring"] = 50;
 mymap["b_string"] = 100;
```

I assume that's what you need, if I'm incorrect let me know.
Also, remeber to advise this: http://en.cppreference.com

You can always find basic concepts and a lot of examples for STL functions of C++.

Comment: Thanks for your input. It would have helped if I had posted my question correctly the first time. :P